# How do I make tspan inherits the parent text x? (Positioning multiline tspan in text)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, text

I have an app that allow user to draw SVG multiline texts. I checked multiple solutions on StackOverflow and `tspan` seems to be the best, however I have the issue when the parent `text` is not positioned at the left (i.e `x` is not 0):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <text x="100" y="100">
    <tspan>A</tspan>
    <tspan dx="0" dy="1.2em">B</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">C</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the `B` line doesn't move back at all and the `C` line is moved to the left of the whole canvas instead of at `text`'s 100px. Is there anyway other than setting each `tspan` manually?

Comment: Use a transform to set the position. Or since it's your app, set the x to the initial parent x value.